# Highlight my selected 3D buildings in ArcGIS JavaScript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I tried to query and select my 3D buildings related to their names or heights and can achieve the selection but I want to highlight selected ones. How can I do that?

Or is there any better way to select them?

JavaScript code:

```
    document.getElementById("first").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      extrudedBuildings.definitionExpression = "Tipi = 'Mühendislik'";    
    });
    document.getElementById("second").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      extrudedBuildings.definitionExpression = "Tipi = 'Özel'";
    });
    document.getElementById("third").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      extrudedBuildings.definitionExpression = "Tipi = 'İİBF'";
    });
    document.getElementById("fourth").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      extrudedBuildings.definitionExpression = "Tipi = 'Resmi'";
    });
    document.getElementById("fifth").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      extrudedBuildings.definitionExpression = "Tipi = 'Rektörlük'";
    });
    document.getElementById("sixth").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      extrudedBuildings.definitionExpression = "Tipi = 'Yemekhane'";
    });
    document.getElementById("seventh").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      extrudedBuildings.definitionExpression = "Tipi = 'Kütüphane'";
    });
```

HTML Code:

```
          <div id="topbar_4">

            <button id="first" class="esri-button  esri-button--primary">Mühendislik Binaları</button>
            <button id="second" class="esri-button  esri-button--secondary">Özel Binalar</button>
            <button id="third" class="esri-button  esri-button--primary">İİBF </button>
            <button id="fourth" class="esri-button  esri-button--secondary">Resmi Binalar</button>
            <button id="fifth" class="esri-button  esri-button--primary">Rektörlük </button>
            <button id="sixth" class="esri-button  esri-button--secondary">Yemekhane </button>
            <button id="seventh" class="esri-button  esri-button--primary">Kütüphane </button>
            <table width="100%">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attributes) attribute  and use that in the definition query and add in a common class. You can then query all the buttons to [add listeners to them in a loop](https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-add-event-listener-multiple-elements-javascript/) using that common class and use the value in the definition expression.

HTML

```
<button id="first" class="esri-button  esri-button--primary  definitionExpression" value="Mühendislik Binaları">Mühendislik Binaları</button>
<button id="second" class="esri-button  esri-button--secondary  definitionExpression" value="Özel Binalar" >Özel Binalar</button>
<button id="third" class="esri-button  esri-button--primary  definitionExpression" value="İİBF">İİBF </button>
```

Javascript

```
document.querySelectorAll('.definitionExpression').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    extrudedBuildings.definitionExpression = `Tipi = '${event.target.value}'`;
  })
});
```